# Can't run Nativescript on IOS Device version 12.0.1

Tags: ios, nativescript

Simply installed fresh Nativescript app

`tns create my-blank-ng --template tns-template-blank-ng`

`tns run ios`

The result:

Xcode build...
2018-10-20 10:55:37.634 xcodebuild[68905:1199941] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging *createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/y*/qn0qctcs35ngpsdg8px68sw80000gn/T/myblankng_2018-10-20_10-55-37.632.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: Failed to verify bitcode in TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/y_/qn0qctcs35ngpsdg8px68sw80000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.I2l/Root/Payload/myblankng.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets (armv7)

Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to verify bitcode in TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/y_/qn0qctcs35ngpsdg8px68sw80000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.I2l/Root/Payload/myblankng.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets (armv7)

" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify bitcode in TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/y_/qn0qctcs35ngpsdg8px68sw80000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.I2l/Root/Payload/myblankng.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets (armv7)

}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: d35214064b4a1a1c8c7e0da8cf0ec4a5f0cf6706. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70.
Executing after-watch hook from /path/my-blank-ng/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js

Update:

NS version: 3.4.3

XCODE Version 10.0 (10A255)

Comment: what is version of xcode and NS you are using?

Comment: NS version: 3.4.3  -  XCODE Version 10.0 (10A255)

Comment: Do you want to try with updated NS?

Comment: Unfortunately, after updating NS to "4.2.4" the same issue.

Comment: Mostly this error comes when you are trying to publish the app via Xcode. Can you please verify witch apple certificate/ provision profile you areusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad.
I just had to update "Angular", "Nativescript" and "tns-core-modules" to the latest version.